# Nuts for 2008 VW Jetta SE 2.5L battery terminal bolts: 1/4" or M6?

Tags: battery, wiring, nut

I want to use an external charger to charge the battery in my US-market 2008 Jetta 2.5L SE with an OEM battery.

I need to figure out which nuts to get to fit the existing battery terminal bolt, in order to use the ring terminal attachment of the charger.

I've gotten some M6 nuts at Home Depot, however, they didn't seem to screw-on at all.  I've then gotten 1/4" ones, and they only seem to screw between maybe 180° and 240° on one of the bolts, and maybe at most 90° onto the other bolt (I haven't tried using any tools, just hands).

**Do I use 1/4" or M6?  Or something else entirely?**

**What would be the best way to attach the ring terminals of the charger to the car?**

Comment: Do you have or can you find a picture of what you currently have?

Comment: Sounds like the pitch of the nuts you bought is wrong.

Comment: They should be straight forward metric nuts. As there may have been some reason to change the bolts previously, why not take one of the bolts with you to HomeDepot and offer them up. You could of course give one of the bolts to the 'wife' and ask her to get them :-).

Comment: And when I said, "picture of what you currently have", I'm talking about the vehicle end, not what you bought at Home Depot. If we have a picture of where you are trying to attach it, we could give you advice on *where* to put it. More than likely you can utilize what you have without putting any further additions.

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so, we'd love to hear about it!

Comment: @Zaid, unfortunately, no!  I abandoned the whole idea, those external chargers are all smart nowadays, and do nothing to restore a battery in a car that's already driven at least weekly, and without easy access to an outlet anyways.